# NSIS: Use selected language for MessageBox in .onInit (MUI2)

Tags: nsis

I try to get a localized message box in the .onInit method which fails with the following code:

```
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "German"

LangString Message ${LANG_ENGLISH} "This is a message."
LangString Message ${LANG_GERMAN} "Dies ist eine Nachricht"

Function .onInit
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
  MessageBox MB_OK "$(Message)"
FunctionEnd
```

The MessageBox always shows the same language string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is, that the language is processed *after* the .onInit method.

A workaround for this could be to put the custom code from the .onInit method to the .onGUIInit method.

With MUI2 this is done as follows:

```
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT myGuiInit

!include "MUI2.nsh"

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "German"

LangString Message ${LANG_ENGLISH} "This is a message."
LangString Message ${LANG_GERMAN} "Dies ist eine Nachricht"

Function .onInit
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
FunctionEnd

Function myGuiInit
  MessageBox MB_OK "$(Message)"
FunctionEnd
```

Now the MessageBox should show the correctly localized message.

Comment: In your description, you describe using the function .onGUIInit, which is one of the built-in ones, but in your code you use a custom named function called myGuiInit...which one is the way to go?

Comment: @JessicaBrown he uses a custom function, because it's not possible to use the `.onGUIInit` function with MUI. MUI defines its own init function. The only way is to write a custom function and to supply it with `!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT myGuiInit`? but this define should be before the MUI include. There is a line on top of the answer, see?